# material slider onInit callBack

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I have a problem with a material slider similar to this one:

https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider/issues/79

The value is not loading, I suppose that the component is not initialized (ready) when the value is set. (it is odd cause its just hidden, it's not like it's not created because of an ngIf...).

With a simple setTimeout it works correctly, but **I like to know if there is an event fired when the component is ready (from the slider or angular)**.

I take a look at the API (https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api) but is very short.

I dont know if it can be relevant but here is the code that im using to define it:

```
<div [style.display]="isEditing ? 'block' : 'none'">
<form autocomplete="off" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="1" [(ngModel)]="editObject.difficulty" name="difficulty"></mat-slider>
</form>
</div>
```

And in the component:

```
  edit(editId: number, form: NgForm) {

    debugger;
    form.reset();

    if (editId && editId > 0) {
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(element => {
        if (element.id === editId) {
          setTimeout(() => { this.editObject = element; }, 100);
          //his.editObject = element;
          console.log(this.editObject);
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.initEditObject();
    }

    this.isEditing = true;
  }
```

The dataSource.data is a list of elements from material table.

Comment: Your `mat-slider` definition in the template looks fine. Please also share the code from the component class.

Comment: I edited the question to extend the code information. With the commented line, it does not work, with the timeout it does. The edit object has the correct value, checked with developer console.

Comment: where you call `edit` function? Did you try calling it in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: The edit function is called from a button in each row of a material table (to edit an element, with an editId >0), or from a button outside the table, to create a new element (with editId =0).

Comment: Creating a stackblitz sample would be nice and make it easier to provide an answer.